# What does "Can't send message on card 1, error 21" mean?

Tags: sms, system-error, google-messages

I'm trying to send an SMS with Messenger on my new Nexus 5X running Lollipop, but sending always fails with `Can't send message on card 1, error 21`.  Receiving SMS and making phone calls works fine.  What's going on?

Comment: Please check **message service center settings** for SIM1/2 and uncheck  **use same service center for sending/receiving messages** in Message settings. This is the most common problem if everything else is fine.

Comment: I got this error when my phone bill was overdue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely **the destination phone number is formatted wrong**, which can happen particularly when importing contacts via third-party tool.

In this particular case, I used *My Contacts Backup* for iOS to export my contacts to VCF, then imported from Gmail.  In the process, some numbers were wrongly formatted as `+61 0 4xx` when they should be just `+61 4xx`, causing the highly uninformative error message above.  (The `21` error code actually comes from the operator's network, and has nothing to do with Android as such.)  Removing the extra `0` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If above mentioned methods are not working, you may try installing 3rd party SMS applications (eg., EvolveSMS) instead of Google messenger. Hope it helps.